# Missing SagePay RelatedSecurityKey

Tags: opayo

I am writing a refund function for our ecommerce site and I'm getting error code 3033 : The RelatedSecurityKey is required.
I have checked and the documentation says this key should be returned when the original transaction was made. We save the details without any modifications to the database, but I can't find it. The return values for my test transaction are:

> VendorTxCode=241****
>
> &VPSTxId={EBA625AB-955E-75C8-4409-*************}
>
> &Status=OK
>
> &StatusDetail=0000 : The Authorisation was Successful.
>
> &TxAuthNo=763****
>
> &AVSCV2=SECURITY CODE MATCH ONLY
>
> &AddressResult=NOTMATCHED
>
> &PostCodeResult=NOTMATCHED
>
> &CV2Result=MATCHED
>
> &GiftAid=0
>
> &3DSecureStatus=NOTCHECKED
>
> &CardType=VISA
>
> &Last4Digits=0006
>
> &Amount=25.00

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

SecurityKey - Only present if Status is OK.

To register the initial transaction, you post to Sage Pay via the Transaction Registration URL (A1).

Sage Pay send a server reponse to the tranasction registration POST in the Server protocol (see A2 in Sage Pay Server Protocol). The response includes the following - VPSProtocol, Status, StatusDetail, VPSTxId, SecurityKey and NextURL.

[A Security key which Sage Pay uses to generate a MD5 Hash to sign the Notification message (step A3 from the Sage Pay Server protocol, which is the example you are providing in response to the Notification post via the Notification URL). The signature is called VPSSignature. This value is used to allow detection of tampering with notifications from the Sage Pay Server. It must be kept secret from the Customer and held in your database. Only present if Status is OK.] You need the SecurityKey incase want to refund against the transaction in future as this will become the RelatedSecurityKey.

The NextURL redirects the customer/shopper to the Sage Pay payment page.

Sage Pay then notify you via the NotificationURL with the VPSSignature. (A3)

You then acknowledge receipt of the post and the customer is redirected via the RedirectURL back to a page on your website.

Comment: I have face the issue see the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672527/the-relatedsecuritykey-is-required-in-sageapy

Comment: How do we get the SecurityKey and store it in database. can you please  explain with the code or an example